# How to correctly set up the time element markup for a line with a duration, day, date and time

Tags: html, datetime, time, semantic-markup

I am somehow confused how to properly markup the following example:

```
The course takes 2 days
from Sunday, 12.06.2014 9:00-18:00
to Monday, 13.06.2014 9:00-14:00
```

I came up with the following but i am uncertain if that is the correct proper way:

```
<p>The course takes <time datetime="P 2 D">2 days</time></p>
<p> from <time datetime="2014-06-12">Sunday, 12.06.2014 </time><time datetime="2014-06-12T9:00+1:00">9:00</time>-<time datetime="2014-06-12T18:00+1:00">18:00</time></p>
<p> to <time datetime="2014-06-13">Monday, 13.06.2014 </time><time datetime="2014-06-13T9:00+1:00">9:00</time>-<time datetime="2014-06-13T14:00+1:00">14:00</time></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `time` element represents its contents, along with a machine-readable form of those contents in the `datetime` attribute. The kind of content is limited to various kinds of dates, times, time-zone offsets, and durations.
>
> [The `time` element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#the-time-element)

Semantically your markup is ok.

However, there are few issues with `datetime` attribute:

- Remove whitespaces from [duration string](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/infrastructure.html#valid-duration-string): `P 2 D` --> `P2D`.
- An hour in [time string](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/infrastructure.html#valid-time-string) and [time-zone offset string](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/infrastructure.html#valid-time-zone-offset-string) must consist of 2 digits: `2014-06-12T9:00+1:00` --> `2014-06-12T09:00+01:00`.

After fix:

```
<p>The course takes <time datetime="P2D">2 days</time></p>
<p> from <time datetime="2014-06-12">Sunday, 12.06.2014 </time><time datetime="2014-06-12T09:00+01:00">9:00</time>-<time datetime="2014-06-12T18:00+01:00">18:00</time></p>
<p> to <time datetime="2014-06-13">Monday, 13.06.2014 </time><time datetime="2014-06-13T09:00+01:00">9:00</time>-<time datetime="2014-06-13T14:00+01:00">14:00</time></p>
```